# Is there a way to attach the color picker to the toolbox in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I don't know how to lock the color picker to the toolbox or if there is a way to do so, if someone could tell me id appreciate it, I'm not used to gimp and hate dragging the window everywhere.
thanks :D

Comment: The **Colour Picker** should already be in the **Toolbox**...or are you referring to the Colour Picker Options that show up in **Tool Options** when the Colour Picker is selected? You can set GIMP to Single-Window Mode from the **Windows** command menu.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to attach the color picker window.  There is a colors tab you can enable on either side however that works like the color picker window.

Click the left-point triangle button in one of the tab areas to open the tab menu.  Select the 'Add tab' sub-menu and then the 'Colors' item.

Answer (score 0):

As of Gimp 2.10.8, there is *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Color*, which produces such a picker as a toolbox panel, that can then be attached to one of the side-panels. If also offers the various methods of color selection.

[image]

[image]